# How to write "ToDo" comments in Source Insight editor?

Tags: editor, source-insight

I want to know, How can we write To DO comments in Source insight editor so that they'll get highlighted automatically ?

Comment: You can make up your own todo comments - see this [question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253300/source-insight-todo-comment

Answer (score 1):

Start you TODO comment with `// TODO:`