# Source Insight //TODO comment

Tags: c++, source-insight

I recently started working with Source Insight, and in order to get a proper looking //TODO - comment you need to write `// TODO`
(with an extra space).

I tried looking around the config for a way to remove this extra space, couldn't find it, and can't get used to writing it with the extra space.

Any way to solve this? Or should I embrace this, and then slowly, learn to cherish it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Go to Options->Style Properties
- Add a new Style for your "todo" comments, set its properties to be whatever you like
- Go to Options->Document Options
- Click on "Language" button in Parsing   section
- Select appropriate language (C? C++?)
- Click "Properties"
- Change to "Comments and Ranges" tab
- Click "Add new definition"
- Set formatting style to match the new one you created above
- For "range begins with" put "//todo" (perhaps one for each type of
  capitalisation)
- Click ok x 3
- Yes to "Reparse project"
- Click close

It should now be showing up properly!

Comment: Thank you! was waiting quite some time for this :)